# Teradata ODBC connection issue: No version information available (required by ./tdxodbc64) on ubuntu

Tags: odbc, ubuntu-14.04, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

We are facing the following issue while connecting to teradata server. Driver v16.10 and ubuntu v14.04.

> /opt/teradata/client/16.10/bin$ ./tdxodbc64 -c SQLDriverConnect -t -S 'SERVER_IP' -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD'
>
> ./tdxodbc64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so: no version
>   information available (required by ./tdxodbc64)
>
> ./tdxodbc64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so: no version
>   information available (required by ./tdxodbc64)
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is resolved by set the environmental variables

> export ODBCINI="/opt/teradata/client/16.10/odbc_64/odbc.ini"
>   export ODBCINSTINI="/opt/teradata/client/16.10/odbc_64/odbcinst.ini"
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/teradata/client/16.10/odbc_64/lib:/opt/teradata/client/16.10/odbc_64/odbc.ini:/opt/teradata/client/16.10/odbc_64/odbcinst.ini"